# Para que serve o tipo "never"?

Tags: typescript, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Hoje me perguntaram para que serve o tipo `never` do TypeScript, porém ficou confuso pra mim. Ele serve apenas para dizer que não retorna nada? Qual a diferença para o `void`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `never`

O tipo `never` indica que a função nunca retorna algo. Ou seja, funções que geram erro ou geram um *loop* infinito possuem o seu retorno definido como `never`. Citando a [documentação](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never), em tradução livre:

> O tipo `never` representa o tipo de valores que nunca ocorrem. Por
> exemplo, `never` é o tipo de retorno para uma função ou para uma
> *arrow function* que sempre lança uma exceção ou uma que
> nunca retorna; As variáveis também adquirem o tipo `never` quando
> estreitadas por qualquer tipo de proteção que nunca possa ser verdadeira.
>
> O tipo `never`é um subtipo de e pode ser atribuído a todo tipo; no
> entanto, nenhum tipo é um subtipo de, ou pode ser atribuído a, `never`
> (exceto o próprio `never`). Mesmo `any` não é atribuível ao `never`.
>
> ```js
> // Uma função retornando "never" deve ter um ponto final inacessível
> function error(message: string): never {
>     throw new Error(message);
> }
>
> // O tipo de retorno inferido é "never"
> function fail() {
>     return error("Aconteceu um erro!");
> }
>
> // Uma função retornando "never" deve ter um ponto final inacessível
> function infiniteLoop(): never {
>     while (true) {
>     }
> }
> ```

### Exemplos

Uma diferença entre o `void` e o `never` é que o tipo `void` pode receber o valor `undefined`, enquanto o tipo `never` não pode receber nenhum valor (apenas si mesmo, `never`).

Deixei o exemplo abaixo no [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tipo-never-no-typescript-g8zo1?) para que seja possível visualizar os resultados e os erros de *lint*.

```js
function funcaoVoid(): void {
  console.log("Executando funcaoVoid");
}

function funcaoNeverLoop(): never {
  // Essa função gera um erro de loop infinito
  console.log("Executando funcaoNeverLoop");
  while (true) {}
}

function funcaoNeverErro(): never {
  console.log("Executando funcaoNeverErro");
  throw new Error("Erro gerado");
}

// Void
console.log('Chamada "funcaoVoid()":', funcaoVoid());

// Never - Loop
try {
  console.log('Chamada "funcaoNeverLoop()":', funcaoNeverLoop());
} catch {
  console.log('A função "funcaoNeverLoop()" foi chamada e entrou no "catch"');
}

// Never - Error
try {
  console.log('Chamada "funcaoNeverErro()":', funcaoNeverErro());
} catch {
  console.log('A função "funcaoNeverErro()" foi chamada e entrou no "catch"');
}

// Veja o erro em attr
const attr: never = undefined;
const attr2: void = undefined;

// O console.log() funciona para attr pois a tipagem em TS é apenas em tempo de compilação.
console.log(attr, attr2);
```

Os resultados no console são:

> ```
> Executando funcaoVoid
> Chamada "funcaoVoid()": undefined
> Executando funcaoNeverLoop 
> A função "funcaoNeverLoop()" foi chamada e entrou no "catch" 
> Executando funcaoNeverErro 
> A função "funcaoNeverErro()" foi chamada e entrou no "catch" 
> undefined undefined
> ```

Comment: Nao consigo ver uma utilidade e nunca nem vi codigo usando `never`, mas parece que ele seria usado somente em funcao que iria tratar uma mensagem e depois lancar um erro. Teria alguma utilidade com esse tipo? Primeira vez que eu ouvi falar nele e achei meio estranho, pois achava que o `void` era suficiente. Ou talvez o IntelliSense mostre que a funcao estar do tipo `never` pra chamar a atencao do desenvolvedor para algum erro que gera loop infinito... nao sei.

Comment: Pela pesquisa que fiz na internet, para funções só encontrei esses dois exemplos, sendo o de gerar erro o caso mais útil (uma função que gera um erro padrão pra você). Acredito que o melhor ganho nisso seja na hora de chamar essa função e você reparar que ela é do tipo `never` e já conseguir entender na hora o que pode acontecer, fora isso não encontrei outros pontos que me chamaram atenção

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @RafaelTavares, estou excluindo a antiga resposta para evitar problemas de interpretação

Answer (score 2):

Conforme consta na [documentação](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never):

> O tipo `never` é um subtipo e atribuível a qualquer outro tipo. No entanto, nenhum tipo é subtipo ou atribuível a ele (exceto o próprio `never`). Até `any` não é atribuível a `never`.

É basicamente um tipo que não pode acontecer. A sua inexistência é um fato.

Não vou prolongar muito em relação à definição, já que a própria documentação e as outras respostas aqui já fornecem esse tipo de informação.

---

Não é válido comparar `void` com `never`, já que aquele representa um valor que existe (geralmente `undefined`) e este não existe, logo não representa nenhum valor possível. Note que `void` representa a ausência de tipo (é o oposto de `any`), enquanto `never` representa a impossibilidade de se haver um valor – aplicável apenas para ao tipo `never`.

---

É raro encontrar algum caso de uso para `never`, mas há situações em que ele é especialmente útil. Geralmente, para [estreitar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401500/o-que-s%C3%A3o-convers%C3%B5es-widening-e-narrowing) um conjunto, como uma [união](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) de tipos. Por exemplo, podemos criar um tipo que remove `number`s e `string`s:

```
type NonNumberString<T> = T extends string | number ? never : T;

type All = undefined | null | string | number | boolean | symbol;

// %inferred-type: boolean | symbol | null | undefined
type Filtered = NonNumberString<All>;
```

<sup>[Veja no TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=38#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOxgVwLYCMICcDKwsCWCA5gDwAqAfFALxTlQQAewECAJgM5Sf5HFQAPlARpMWKAH4REAG7YoALnoBuAFBrQkKAEEANntpRkHCADMiEdkJHIDN3oRI3RGBcPRw4eiAEMEDiAY3upqAPRhUACkRGbYWFYAtFoQyp7efgHCnEGehsKi9sIm7OaW7Jrg0ABiBHqsCdZ08Ehi2HhOZPp6lCpAA)</sup>

Basicamente, o tipo `NonNumberString` utiliza de um tipo condicional para verificar se `T` é atribuível a `number` ou `string`. Se sim, `never` será *retornado*. Caso contrário, `T` será retornado. Isso remove, ou seja, afina o nosso tipo, excluindo `string` ou `number`.

Nesse caso específico, o tipo embutido [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) (veja exemplo [aqui](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnKBeKBXAdgEwgMwJboSZQA%20U6qCpUAzsAE4EDm1FAtgEYT3UcD2fOBACG6ajRCdBAbgBQsgPQKoAUgI5u9IgFpQkAFxR%20gkWLISpiMhSpkM2fIUyy90AGJ44wbkWRQAogAeAMZwqNgAPPBwADTkqJzc4gzMAHzSQA)) chega ao mesmo resultado. A intenção aqui é exemplificar um caso de uso de estreitamento de tipos utilizando o `never`.

Um outro caso de uso interessante é garantir, através da análise de fluxo de código do TypeScript, que uma variável tem o tipo `never`, ou seja, não pode ter valor. Este [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aldIFYWu6xc) explica isso com mais detalhes.

Answer (score -1):

Sinceramente nunca vi um código com o tipo never na prática, mas em teoria, representa algo que nunca deve ocorrer. Resumindo: nunca retorna algo e é diferente do tipo void. Ademais, o type void pode receber o valor null ou undefined e o type never não pode receber nenhum valor.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).