# O que são conversões Widening e Narrowing?

Tags: .net, terminologia, característica-linguagem, conversão-de-tipo

Ouvi esse termo em conversões de tipos em .NET, mas não sei se isso se aplica a outras plataformas e/ou linguagens.

Não faço ideia do que seja estes termos, então, o que é uma conversão **Narrowing** e uma **Widening**? Quais suas diferenças e onde uso elas?

Comment: Acredito que já deva ter lido nisto: [Widening and Narrowing Conversions (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/widening-and-narrowing-conversions) . Porém está muito técnico e difícil compreensão. .

Comment: @LuizAugusto eu cheguei a ler aí, mas pelo mesmo motivo eu não tive uma boa compreensão na diferença dos dois. Na verdade, nem sequer entendi o que são eles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *Widening*

É pegar um valor e tratá-lo como algo mais amplo, ou seja, você pega um valor que tem uma magnitude menor e coloca em um tipo que permite uma magnitude maior, portanto nunca haverá perda de dados. Algumas pessoas acham que há sempre uma conversão nesses casos, mas isto não é verdade, existe em alguns casos, mas não em todos. O mais importante é que **é seguro fazer este tipo de operação**.

Ele não é complicado de entender, se você tem um número que está guardado em 2 bytes, e tem um local na memória que está preparado para acomodar um número que ocupa 4 bytes, ele coloca os 2 bytes lá e completa  os outros 2 bytes com zeros não significativos nos outros bytes pra não deturpar o valor (o local exato [depende da arquitetura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50457/101), mas não precisa se preocupar com isso). Algo assim (exemplificando com decimal para visualizar melhor, mas na memória é tudo binário) pense que você tem espaço para 8 dígitos em algum lugar, o número original só tem 4:

```
1234
00001234
```

Um exemplo bem comum é colocar um valor `int` em uma variável ou *slot* em expressão que espera um *long*, esse valor será tratado como um `long` normalmente sem problemas.

É comum as linguagens deixarem fazer isto implicitamente (algumas não deixam). Mas não quer dizer que nunca tem problemas, não há perda, mas pode gerar resultados não esperados em algumas situações mais específicas, por exemplo quando muda de `float` para `double` ou `decimal` para `double` já que esses tipos tem [problemas de exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Além disso am alguns casos a operação de *widening* pode gerar estouro em outras que não poderia.

## *Narrowing*

É o oposto, então é tentar colocar um valor de maior magnitude onde só cabe um de menor magnitude. Obviamente que em muitos casos haverá perda de dados, seja precisão ou exatidão, em alguns casos com grandes diferenças, já que não tem espaço para guardar toda informação necessária. Há casos que o valor pode ser acomodado no tipo menor sem maiores problemas. Também não quer dizer que exista conversão, mas sem uma conversão a chance de erro é maior.

Aqui é mais complicado entender um pouco então vou tentar usar o exemplo anterior para mostrar o que acontece. Agora você tem o número original com os mesmos 4 dígitos, mas só tem espaço para 2 deles na memória, o que acontece?

```
1234
12
```

Notou a perda, né? Fica terrível, o valor passa não ter sentido algum.
Um exemplo típico é tentar colocar um valor `int` em um tipo `short` que tem metade do tamanho em memória e portanto pode representar valores bem menores que o `int`pode.

Outro exemplo que as pessoas não se dão conta e por isso o uso é perigoso é tentar colocar um valor não sinalizado (`unsigned`) em um tipo sinalizado, apesar deles terem as mesma quantidade de bits um desses bits é usado para o sinal então o valor máximo que ele permite é menor, tem casos de um laço se tornar infinito por causa disto, já que o valor vai crescendo até que uma hora ele "do nada" se torna negativo, e aí nunca chega na condição que o encerraria e você nem viu o valor mudar. Esse é um dos motívos que se fala para evitar `unsigned` ao máximo.

Também é comum uma operação aritmética criar um valor que estoure o tipo normalmente usado e uma operação de *narrow* pode acontecer implicitamente, por exemplo: multiplicar 1 bilhão por 1000 não cabe em um inteiro apesar que originalmente 1 bilhão cabia e se tudo estava esperando usar era um `int` alguma perda pode ocorrer porque houve um *widening* implícito na multiplicação e depois houve um *narrowing* para caber no espaço que tinha originalmente.

Nenhuma linguagem completamente sã deveria deixar fazer isto implicitamente (mas quase todas deixam de uma forma ou outra, algumas mudam a representação do número para caber assim mesmo, mas não no .NET). É complicado para as linguagens impedirem em todas circunstância e deixaria tudo muito ineficiente, o C# tem como [ligar isso em algumas circunstâncias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157342/101) (não resolve todos problemas). Mesmo explicitamente é preciso tomar cuidado porque pode haver perda se você não tiver certeza do que está fazendo, algo assim: `(short)1234`. Mas tem casos que não tem problema, exemplo aqui ocorre o *narrowing* de 8 dígitos para 4 e não tem perda:

```
00001234
1234
```

Claro, o assunto é mais complexo, envolvem outros tipos que permitem seus valores serem interpretados como outros tipos com ou sem perda porque o tipo destino é mais ou menos amplo, mas a base é esta.

## Hierarquia

Isto pode acontecer com hierarquia. Se um objeto deriva de outro é comum que ele tenha novos campos que a derivada não tinha (nem tão comum assim, mas razoavelmente), se você for tentar colocar o tipo derivado em um local que estava esperando o tipo base não cabe então alguma coisa será perdida. Pode ser que não cause um grande problema na hora porque seu código não poderá acessar nada do tipo derivado mesmo, mas se depois você tentar pegar esse objeto como o tipo derivado o dado específico do derivado não estará lá. Isto se chama *slicing*.

Por sorte o .NET não deixa você fazer isso, como só poderia fazer algo assim em tipos por referência então sempre tem espaço para o tipo derivado todo estar na memória (agradeça a [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101)) e tipos por valor não tem herança então não tem como acontecer esse fenômeno ([em C/C++ pode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286437/101)). Por isso não dei maiores detalhes.

Aí começa ficar confuso porque quando você converte de um tipo derivado para um base tem perda, mesmo que não de dados, mas de comportamentos (alguns métodos que existem no tipo derivado pode não existir no tipo base, bem comum), chama isto de *widening* já que o tipo é mais geral.

E quando converte o tipo base para um tipo derivado chama-se *narrowing* já que ele passar ser um tipo mais específico, mas este é um caso que ele ganha capacidade em vez de perder.

Mas eu entendo que a motivação é porque fazer o *widening* sempre funciona (pelo menos se passar na compilação), afinal o tipo original sempre é compatível com sua base, e o contrário nem sempre funciona já que o objeto precisa ser compatível e ele pode não ser, por isso precisa ser de forma explícita, por isso chamaram de *narrowing*, é consistente nesse aspecto.

Eu acho que nestes casos deveria só chamar de *upcasting* e *downcasting* respectivamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).