# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

Tags: react, typescript

Estou tendo problemas em fazer este pequeno pedaço de código funcionar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o meu código:

```
import React, {SetStateAction} from 'react';
import {BsCheck, BsTrashFill} from 'react-icons/bs';

type Props = {
  text: string,
  todos: SetStateAction<never[]>,
  setTodos: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<never[]>>
}

const Todo: React.FC<Props> = ({text, todos, setTodos}) => {
  const deleteHandler = () => {
    setTodos(todos.filter(el => el.id !== todos.id))
  }

  return(
    <div className="todo">
      <li className="todo-item">{text}</li>
      <BsCheck className="check" size={35}/>
      <BsTrashFill onClick={deleteHandler} className="trash" size={35}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

Os erros são:

> Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
> Property 'filter' does not exist on type '(prevState: never[]) =>
> never[]'.
>
> Parameter 'el' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never[]'.

Comment: Você sabe o que é o tipo [`never`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/299914/69296)? Não faz muito sentido utilizá-lo aí...

Comment: como comentou o @LuizFelipe, uma vez que foi usado o tipo `never`, não deve estar tratando por um válido de array, por isso o `filter` não pode ser usado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente escrever isso usando `any[]`:

```
type Props = {
  text: string,
  todos: any[],
  setTodos: (todos: any[]) => void
}
```

Ou você pode escrever `interface ITodo` como:

```
interface ITodo {
  id: number
  name: string
  // ..
}

type Props = {
  text: string,
  todos: ITodo[],
  setTodos: (todos: ITodo[]) => void
}
```

Porque, em React, `Dispatch` é definido como:

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void; // Function
```

E `SetStateAction`:

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S); // Function Ou Value
```

E você precisa de `idToDelete` assim:

```
const deleteHandler = (idToDelete) => {
  setTodos(todos.filter(el => el.id !== idToDelete))
}
```

Comment: Acho que vale a pena explicar também porque o código da AP não funciona. Muitas vezes, inclusive, usar `any` não é o ideal, até porque ele anula uma série de benefícios que fazem a pessoa ir para o TypeScript em primeiro lugar.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Ok, eu vou escrever sobre isso. Obrigado :)

Comment: Agora tenho este erro: Property 'todos' is missing in type '{ setTodos: (todos: ITodo[]) => void; key: number; text: string; }' but required in type 'Props'. Acho que não funcionou muito bem